# An empty row is getting added to the Datagrid bound to the data table when user sets focus on the cell of already existing empty row.

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid

I have a datagrid which is bound to a datatable. User can insert values in the Datagrid cells.
When user sets focus through mouse on any datagrid cell and hits enter key, A new empty row gets added to the Datagrid at the last.
(Which is correct, It should be like that)

The Problem is - When user hits Enter key on an empty row and then sets the mouse focus on the first cell of that empty row, 
Another empty row is getting added (So there are two empty rows seen). How can i prevent an empty row from getting added when already an empty row exist ?

[image]

This is what I've tried:

### View.xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"                           
                          Height="400"
                          Width="Auto"
                          SelectionMode="Single"                        
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                          GridLinesVisibility ="Vertical"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeRows="False"                
                          BorderThickness="0" 
                          CanUserAddRows="True" 
                          RowEditEnding="EntityGrid_RowEditEnding"
                          RowHeaderWidth="0">                                                  
</DataGrid>
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
private DataTable _MyDataTable;

public DataTable MyDataTable
{
    get { return _MyDataTable; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _MyDataTable, value); }
}
```

### View.xaml.cs

```
 private void EntityGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
            {
                var bindingGroup = e.Row.BindingGroup;
                if (bindingGroup != null && bindingGroup.CommitEdit())
                {
                    var item = (DataRowView)e.Row.Item;

                    if (AreAllCellsEmpty(item.Row))
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        ((DataGrid)sender).CancelEdit();

                        var row_list = GetDataGridRows((DataGrid)sender);

                        foreach (DataGridRow datagridRow in row_list)
                        {
                            if (datagridRow.IsSelected == true)
                            {
                                datagridRow.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```